# How to perform routing in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xml, angular-routing

I have an xml file and i tried to give routing as follows,

```
   state('blog.bloglist', {
        url: '/blog-list',
        templateUrl: 'feed.xml',
        controller: "blogListCtrl" 
    }).
```

but this shows errors,can some one please help me.

Comment: Not enough info, what is the error?

Comment: My page itself not able to opened

Comment: Do you see a request to feed.xml, using Chrome Developer tools which you can open by hitting F12? Does your server return proper and expected result?

Answer (score 1):

what type of document is feed.xml? what is said in error? perhaps, you dont mentioned the path to templateUrl correctly or templateUrl file is not a valid html-structured file. sample routing example is like this:

```
.state('dashboard', {
        url: "/dashboard.html",
        templateUrl: "views/dashboard.html",            
        controller: "DashboardController"
```

}  //...